# Sun Light not rendering (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

So, I made this scene in blender Eevee, it is not complete yet, but I rendered it to see how it was looking so far, and I noticed that on the rendered viewport, the sun light looks normal, but when I actually render it, it is not visible at all.0[image]

[image]